# Qt button assign command

Tags: qt, qpushbutton

I'm using qt creator to create a gui for an vtk aplication.

I've made a #define action and I want to assign that command to a QPushButton.

How do I make the button reproduce my define if pressed?

example.
ui->pushButton->...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy way is to define a default reponse slot for your button. In your class definition (the same class that defines the pushButton) you can just create a default slot under the `slots` section.

```
class MyMainApplication : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    MyMainApplication(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyMainApplication();

   // More stuff in the public section (...)

  public slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();    // This is the important line

  // The remaining definitions in your class
};
```

Now you just program the `on_pushButton_clicked()` function in your class implementation and it will respond to the click on the button called `pushButton`.

The syntax for default slots is `on_NAMEOFTHEWIDGET_NAMEOFTHESIGNAL`.

With the default slots, the connection is made automatically. If you want to use a generic name for the slot you must make the connection manually. For instance, say that instead of 
`on_pushButton_clicked()` you want to use `mySlot()`. In the class definition you would type

```
(...)
public slots:
  void mySlot();
(...)
```

and in the class implementation, probably in the constructor, after the `ui->setupUi(this);` command you would make the connection of the button and your slot:

```
connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(mySlot()));
```

A final remark: in this particular case, I am almost sure that the slots can also be `private`.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but i have the action that i want the button to take when clicked in the mainwindow.cpp like #define AlignXAxis() and I tried to make it like connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(AlignXAxis())); but it won't work.

Comment: What do you mean by `#define AlignXAxis()`. What you have to do is to put a `void AlignXAxis()` function in the `slots:` area of your class definition, implement the function and then make the connection. As far as I know your `#define` statement will not connect to anything. You must connect a `SIGNAL` (declared in the `signals:` block of the widget) to a `SLOT` (declared in the `slots:` block of the receiving widget). I do not see why you would use `#define` (which, again, as far as I know, does not act as a slot).

Comment: yes, you're right. but when i try to call another function for example void AlignCamera(), it says undefined reference to `AlignCamera()'

Comment: Is `AlignCamera()` defined as a class `slot`? Otherwise, without seeing some code it is impossible to suggest anything else.

Comment: @user1613749 You can only connect to slots, which are methods of QObject/QObject subclasses marked as slot. #define's won't work. (and are considered bad style in C++ by most anyway).

Comment: I defined my function void AlignCamera() in the top level, i mean not inside of any other function. but i can go to mainwindow.h and just put void AlignCamera() in the private slot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Qt's feature called [Signals and Slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/signalsandslots.html). Many objects can send signals when interacted with. Example is "clicked()" signal emitted from a QPushButton, or "triggered()" which is emitted upon clicking on QAction.

Main idea is to connect a signal to a slot. Slots are functions which are called when a signal is emitted. I can provide you with a PyQt example:

`QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.myButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.someFunction)`

C++ code shouldn't be much different. Check the Qt examples, they provide lots of good stuff.